# Ruby undefined local variable byebug

Tags: ruby, debugging, byebug

I'm executing the file app.rb in my rails project and trying to step through it using the byebug gem, but I get an error saying 'byebug' is an undefined local variable.  I'm running the code using the command 'ruby app.rb'.  Is there a different way to step through a ruby file when executing it this way via the command line?

```
    $ bundle install
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/.....
Resolving dependencies...
Using byebug 6.0.2
Installing pg 0.18.3
Using bundler 1.6.2
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
$ ruby app.rb
app.rb:17:in `block in <main>': undefined local variable or method `byebug' for main:Object (NameError)
    from app.rb:15:in `glob'
    from app.rb:15:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 5):

Looks like I just had to add `require "byebug"` at the top my `app.rb` file.

Answer (score 0):

Another debugging option is the `debugger` gem:

```
require 'debugger'; debugger
```

https://github.com/cldwalker/debugger